# Manipulating Text with tkinter

Tags: python, string, tkinter, highlight

My plan was to show strings and then highlist specific letters, depending on the index of the letter.
To give you an idea, this is extly how it should look in the end:
[click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlQoo.jpg)

I wanted to use tkinter and it's canvas, but now I know, that it can't highlight specific letters in a string.

Do you have an idea, how I could do that? I am also open to using something other than tkinter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

so if i understand it correctly u want to just add some text, and then highlight it? id suggest u go to tutorials point, their pretty clear ob how to do it, heres the link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm

heres some code too:

```
from Tkinter import *

def onclick():
   pass

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello.....")
text.insert(END, "Bye Bye.....")
text.pack()

text.tag_add("here", "1.0", "1.4")
text.tag_add("start", "1.8", "1.13")
text.tag_config("here", background="yellow", foreground="blue")
text.tag_config("start", background="black", foreground="green")
root.mainloop()
```

so to move the text the only selution i see is to make the text a variable and then add something like this:

```
text.config(text = '    '+'\n'+'\n'+our_variable_we_used_for_our_text)
```

this would insert some spaces and some newlines, not perfect but i dont think theres something else,

ps.

the \n stands for newline

Comment: Thank you!
But I can't figure out how to change the position of the text.

Comment: i couldnt help you with that either, but id say that either you will have to insert spaces and enters at the right places or you will need to use a canvas, sadly as far as i know you also cant move text in a canvas, so id say to do it something like i added in my answer

Comment: that's a problem, because I need to highlight specific letters depending on their index in the string. And the tag doesn't care about where the string starts, so it throws everything out of whack.
And the canvas is what I initialy wantd to use, but highlighting specific letters doesn't seem to be an option there.
Probably what I need is something completely different.

Comment: yeah, seems like that, as far as i know tkinter wont be able to help u there